# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dlih6aks/MarkupSafe/

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am practicing Docker with https://courses.cognitiveclass.ai/ and I tried to run a `Dockerfile` with the following content.

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
RUN pip install flask
CMD ["python","app.py"]
COPY app.py /app.py
```

The command I used to run `Dockerfile`

```
sudo docker image build -t python-hello-world .
```

when I executed this it was completing only 1/5 step and 2/5 step was failing with following error s.

```
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dlih6aks/MarkupSafe/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 21.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install flask' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Do I need to add any changes to the `Dockerfile`?

References: https://courses.cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork+CO0101EN+v1/courseware/a4f90ba011b740f3b2542acd5fcb7ca6/1baf0640d41543fc9c8b832068551d2c/?child=first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like something's not right with installing Markupsafe>=2 (even on it's own), not sure exactly what it is just yet but as a quick fix you can install previous version before installing flask and it will be replaced with the proper v.2 during flask install but you'll avoid the error:

```
RUN pip install markupsafe==1.1.1 flask
```

**UPDATE**: or even better solution might be to use a more recent python image:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
```